# SQL INSERT INTO statement not inserting data into database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, insert-into

I could not figure out the wrong in this code. Yet, this `insert into` query does not feed data to my SQL Server database.

```
Try
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    connetionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-7I5LAV8T; Initial Catalog=dbTailorMadePeople; User ID=sa; Password=sa1111"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    cnn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand With {.CommandText = "INSERT INTO rsMember(firstName, middleName, lastName, memberID) VALUES ('" & txtFirstName.Text & "', '" & txtMiddleName.Text & "', '" & txtLastName.Text & "', '" & txtID.Text & "')", .Connection = cnn}

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Success")

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Comment: Beside the error, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation. Also: Is there any exception that's thrown?

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns a value that indicated the number of records affected. Can you check the value?

Comment: Your connection is not closed. In your next successive run it will through an exception while opening the connection because it is already open. use  ` cnn.Close()` after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` may be this is why your `insert into...` is not working. IMO you shouldn't not to use `Try..Catch..` block in your development environment. This way you can identify most of the error and fix them else use logging to identify error if used `Try..Catch..` block.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ADO.Net , always parameterized your query to avoid SQL Injection.

```
ex

Dim query as String = String.Empty
query &= "INSERT INTO rsMember(firstName, middleName, lastName, memberID)  "
query &= "VALUES (@firstName,@middleName, @lastName, @memberID)"

Using conn as New SqlConnection("yourConnectionStringHere")
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", strFName)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", strMName)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", strLName)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberID", strMemberID)
        End With
        Try
            conn.open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch(ex as SqlException)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
        End Try
    End Using
End USing
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's just a How-To on parameterised queries.

Comment: I just provide an advice to parameterized his query to avoid sql injection and then I provided working code for me.

Comment: Parameterize - good. Addwithvalue - [bad](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Everyone has something to learn.

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in this line:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand With {.CommandText = "INSERT INTO rsMember values (firstName, middleName, lastName, memberID) VALUES ('" & txtFirstName.Text & "', '" & txtMiddleName.Text & "', '" & txtLastName.Text & "', '" & txtID.Text & "')", .Connection = cnn}
```

Note: Missed Values in sql query

Tip: 1) Before executing the Sql query, temporarily save your sql query in a string.

```
Dim SqlQuery as string ="Your insert query"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand With {.CommandText = SqlQuery  , .Connection = cnn}
```

2) use breakpoint at this line

Dim SqlQuery as string ="Your insert query"

Break while running, get the value from SqlQuery variable and check whether the query is working.

Comment: IN catch block get message and see what is the error

Comment: Don't know why this answer got an up-vote. Solution provided by this user is incorrect. How come there be two `values` keywords in sql query? Kindly go through [HOW TO USE INSERT INTO IN SQL SERVER](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp#div-gpt-ad-1493883843099-0).

Comment: You added an error by including "VALUES" between the inserted table name and the column list.